# Definition of Done/Definition of Ready - Shared for the whole organization?

Tags: agile, scrum, software

Definition of Done and Definition of Ready may be very helpful in the organizations that are new to Agile methodology and Scrum framework.

Must all teams share the same DoD and DoR or it can be adaptable?

Answer (score 2):

The [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) says:

> ... If the definition of "Done" for an increment
>   is part of the conventions, standards or guidelines of the development
>   organization, all Scrum Teams must follow it as a minimum.
>
> If "Done" for an increment is not a convention of the development
>   organization, the Development Team of the Scrum Team must define a
>   definition of "Done" appropriate for the product. If there are
>   multiple Scrum Teams working on the system or product release, the
>   Development Teams on all the Scrum Teams must mutually define the
>   definition of "Done".

In practice, this means that a Scrum Team is responsible for its own Definition of Done. However, an organization may define a minimum Definition of Done, but this does not preclude any team or team's from creating a more comprehensive or more struct Definition. In a scaled environment where multiple teams are collaborating on a single product / Product Backlog, there must be a minimum Definition of Done shared among all of the teams working on the product. Again, the organization's Definition of Done is a baseline for these teams as well.

If you want an explicit hierarchy, the organization's Definition of Done is the baseline. If there is a team-of-teams, the teams must have a shared Definition of Done which can extend the organization's Definition of Done. Individual teams can refine the organization's or the team-of-team's Definition of Done. All teams need a Definition of Done, but it could simply be a reference to a higher level Definition of Done.

Answer (score 0):

The SCRUM guide says:

> If "Done" for an increment is not a convention of the development organization, the Development Team of the Scrum Team must define a definition of "Done" appropriate for the product. If there are multiple Scrum Teams working on the system or product release, the Development Teams on all the Scrum Teams must mutually define the definition of "Done".

So, 'it depends'.

Many times, teams have different backgrounds, different levels of experience, so I would start with a DoD per team.

Comment: teams have different backgrounds, different levels of experience, so I would start with a DoD per team. (Strange, this was in my original post, but it appears to be limited in chars.)